# DNS queries timing out

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, timeout

When I try to perform a name server lookup from the command prompt it times out with the following message:

```
nslookup www.google.de
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  <my IPv6 address>

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Strangely, firefox is able to perform nslookup queries; the Internet connection is statically configured.

Why isn't it possible to launch queries from the command line over the same connection (there is only one active wired connection)?

Comment: Does Firefox use proxy server or there is direct connection?

Comment: Direct connection.

Comment: it is timing out here the same way , because i have the win7 firewall turned on (fully). I believe (not sure) that things like simple pings are by default not on in the firewall?  The only reason i knew the firewall had blocked it, is because i use the program "windows firewall notification" which turns on events for it, and shows them in a pop.  soo check the firewalls? turn on events for the firewall? and check the events log?

Comment: The firewall allows pinging and ns lookups. There isn't anything unusual in the logs either.

Answer (score 1):

The Server part of the nslookup output is saying unknown.

Give this a try, type nslookup by itself and it will go into interactive mode, then specify a server to use.  You could use a local server if you have one or a public DNS server like Google's at 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4.  Lastly type in your query.  Here are the step, press enter after each command:

```
 nslookup
 server 8.8.8.8
 www.google.de
```

You could specify any server that will accept public DNS requests as long as your network allows the traffic out and back in.